# How to train FLAN-T5 to summarization task with a custom dataset of legal documents in pt-br?

Tags: python, nlp, transformer-model, summarization

So, I would like to create a small proof-of-concept using (already extracted in txt files) +- 4.000 legal text divided in:

1. 2.000 initial petitions / complaints *.txt files
2. 2.000 summaries of each initial petition (txt files too)

PS.: **all text files are in brazilian portuguese (pt-br)**

So how can I use these txt files to train a new transformer able to generate new summaries (using flan-t5) ?

Comment: I recommend you take a look here https://colab.research.google.com/github/huggingface/notebooks/blob/main/examples/summarization.ipynb. The approach is not specific to Portuguese but I believe it can work in any language

Comment: You might want to use one of these starting points for your training https://huggingface.co/models?pipeline_tag=summarization&sort=downloads&search=flan-t5. I am not sure if there exist a flan-t5 version already pre-trained on Portuguese text, if not then starting with a model pre-trained in English and fine-tuning it in Portuguese is the best you can do, as I'm assuming you're not intending to pre-train a model from scratch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wrote a post and published a Colab about how this, if you want all of the details and code. [(Post)](https://tripplyons.com/blog/text-summarizer), [(Colab Notebook)](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1ieDHXRIQO98qhwycCpKYqg4OKRs4L8Yf)

The basic steps that I would recommend are:

1. Install the adapter-transformers library. [(Docs)](https://docs.adapterhub.ml/)
2. Use Flan-T5's tokenizer to convert each example from Unicode to the tokens used by Flan-T5. [(Docs)](https://huggingface.co/docs/transformers/main_classes/tokenizer)
3. Fine-tune a set of changes to the weights using LoRA. [(Docs)](https://docs.adapterhub.ml/methods.html#lora)
4. Merge the low-rank changes back into the original weights.

Another way of doing it would be to fine-tune all of the model weights without using adapter methods, but that takes longer and uses more VRAM, without improving performance noticeably.

**Note:** Flan-T5 was mostly trained on English text, which means it won't perform as well on other languages.

Comment: what is the impact of the batch_size on the summaries results?

Comment: The batch size usually does not impact accuracy for a fully trained model. However, a larger batch size requires more memory in order to speed up the training process.

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can get started with this:

1. https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1dul0Sg-TTMy9xZCJzmDRajXbyzDwtYx6?usp=sharing this can be your first starting point for fine-tuning. The author uses it to fine-tune BART, but you can change that.
2. Court transcripts are long, and they often would exceed the length of token size limits if you want to extract everything at once. I'd recommend splitting the data for each transcript.
3. You might also want to look at some cleaning for your dataset.

Here's how I had approached a similar problem but for a different domain: https://aclanthology.org/2022.creativesumm-1.4/